# Cannot add "Flash App" Run/Debug Configuration in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: flash, intellij-idea

I would like to run my flash project, but I cannot add "Flash App" Run/Debug Configuration in IntelliJ Idea

When I click on the plus sign, there's no `Flash App` in it:

[image]

But it appears in the `Defaults`, with an error:

> Build configuration: [none]

[image]

I have Flash plugin and SDK installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the same issue, eventually I removed the "Flash/Flex Support" plugin by going to Preferences > Plugins, restarted IntelliJ, re-enabled the plugin and restarted again. It seemed to sort the issue after I re-imported my Maven project (which didn't resolve the issue before doing this).